# File Not Found Exception : Open failed:ENOENT

Tags: java, android

I am new for android, Im downloading image from URL and set in listView. Its working some mobile and not creating file/directory in some mobile.
Its throw error like:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.tam/veg.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't know why its throw error like this some mobile. I want to create directory all type of mobile. Please anyone help me.

Here my code:

```
public class ImageStorage {
public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    String stored = null;

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), ".tam");//the dot makes this directory hidden to the user
    folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename) ;
    if (file.exists())
        return stored ;
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stored;
}

public static File getImage(String imagename) {

    File mediaImage = null;
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        if (!myDir.exists())
            return null;

        mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/.tam/"+imagename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mediaImage;
}

public static File checkifImageExists(String imagename) {
    File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + imagename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return file;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static String getImageName(String value){

    String getName[] = value.split("/");
    return getName[4];
}
```

}

Below path not in all mobile:

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you added required permissions in Manifest?

Comment: do you have required external permission in manifest?if not have add this **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />**

Comment: I already added permission.. But i check in mobile there is no path like this /storage/emulated/0/

Comment: @hikoo which mobile.?
In every mobile, if you walk through terminal you will get /storage/emulated/0,which is the internal storage or emulated MMC.

Comment: Honor mobile... There is no 0 folder

Comment: `".tam");//the dot makes this directory hidden to the user`. Not at all. Every decent file explorer app can and will show them if the user wants.

Comment: `folder.mkdir();`. You should check if the directory exists before trying to create it. And you should check the return value and inform the user if the directory is not created. And return from the rest of the code: `if ( ! folder.exists() ) if ( !folder.mkdirs()){ toast directory could not be creted; return;}`.

Comment: @greenapps Where i check this condition

Comment: Err guys starting with @JagjitSingh this is not a permissions problem. It is a 'no such file or directory' problem. Do read the question.

Comment: @greenapps I do not agree. `mkdir()` already has to check it. Checking it again is just wasting time and space. It returns an indication of whether it succeeded or not, and *that* is what needs to be checked.

Comment: If the directory already exists will mkdir return true? You suggest it does. Well what's in a name as it did not make it. For better readability i prefer an existance check before calling it.

Comment: I didn't understand.. @greenapps

Comment: Then just do as i suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u should check if there's external storage in the mobile before u use this path

```
public String getDir(Context context) {  
String checkPath = null;  
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())  
        || !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {  
    checkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();  
} else {  
    checkPath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();  
}  
return checkPath;  
}
```

Comment: Where i call this getDir Method

Comment: `check if there's external storage in the mobile`. Not needed. Every mobile has external storage.

Comment: My code only not working  Android 6.0 and above.. How to get permission in marshmallow

Comment: Did u set the targetSdkVersion to 23?